# How do I find to go forward or reverse in two points on a wrapping timeline?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I have a time line of 500 points. On a timeline that wraps around how do I find if the shortest distance between two points is to go forward or backward?

Example,

I'm on frame 30, the target frame is 100 and the total frames are 500.

I know that going it will take 70 frames to get to 100 going forward and 430 to go in reverse but I don't know the codes to figure this out.

I'm using ActionScript but I think I would understand the codes if it were written in other professional languages like JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function shortestDirectionIsForward(current:int, target:int, total:int):Boolean
{
    var forward:int  = target >= current ? target - current : total + target - current;
    var backward:int = target <  current ? current - target : total - target + current;
    return forward < backward;
}
```